# Using same certificates in production and sandbox for SSO(SAML)

Tags: community, single-sign-on, saml, custom-domain

We're using custom domains in sandbox for my communities(2) and performing SSO between them, where one community is acting as an identity provider(IdP) and other as service provider(SP)

To enable SSO we need multiple certificates as per single sign on settings in Salesforce. for e.g. Identity provider certificate, request signing certificate etc

My questions :

1. Do we need to maintain separate certificates(CA signed) for Sandbox and production ? For e.g. for identity provider certificate, should I get 2 certificate signed By CA - one for production and one for Sandbox ?
2. If yes, what will happen after sandbox refresh, do I need to recreate all certificate again after refresh or keep using what was maintained/configured in the production?
3. How should I proceed, if I've multiple sandbox(es) ? I suppose 1'll use same set of CA signed certificates  across all of the sandboxes. Is that correct ?

Comment: 1. Best practice - yes. 2. Yes, update certs on refresh. 3. Best practice - unique cert per party (each sandbox).

Comment: Thanks, But this will add to much to maintenance. As sandbox is for testing, we're thinking to use same set across multiple sandbox and keep Production separate